# Convert Angular 7 project to Angular 7 library

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-library

I have built a project in Angular 7 and in the end to be used by ohters projects,

I wanna convert it to Angular library.

for that, in my Angular project, I generated a library using this cli: `ng g library my-lib`
as you can see the structure bellow:

[image]

How can I move my project features to the created library? In order to use it in an other project later.

Answer (score 2):

move all the components to my-lib & export them in public-api.ts file. Below the reference which will assist you.

https://medium.com/better-programming/angular-7-series-part-2-create-custom-library-8d7a0494b2cc